# Swift - Implementing PageViewController in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Nowhere in internet is explain how to implement PageViewController in your UIViewController
I take this code from default XCode Page-Based Application

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .PageCurl, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
        self.pageViewController!.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)
        // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
        var pageViewRect = self.view.bounds
        self.pageViewController!.view.frame = pageViewRect
        self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        // Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily.
        self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
     //?? what controller should I return
    }
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //?? what controller should I return
    }
}
```

I want to have 6 pages and I want to add text in different pages how to recognize in which page I am and show the info that I want? I want to use only 1 ViewControler, only this view controller.

Answer (score 2):

`UIPageViewController` requires that you use different view controllers. You may need to refactor your code to have a "parent" or "root" view controller, whose only job is to present other view controllers that implement the logic for specific pages. Here's some sample code. It's oversimplified but should give you an idea of how to get going.

```
class PageContent {
    let text: String
    let index: Int
    init(text: String, index: Int) {
        self.text = text
        self.index = index
    }
}

class MyPageViewController : UIViewController {
    var page: PageContent!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Load page data for self.page
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    var pages: [PageContent]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let firstPage = PageContent(text: "...", index: 0)
        let secondPage = PageContent(text: "...", index: 1)
        // ...
        self.pages = [firstPage, secondPage] // add more as necessary
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let beforeController = viewController as MyPageViewController
        let newPageIndex = beforeController.page.index - 1
        if newPageIndex >= 0 {
            let newController = MyPageViewController()
            newController.page = self.pages[newPageIndex]
            return newController
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let afterController = viewController as MyPageViewController
        let newPageIndex = afterController.page.index + 1
        if newPageIndex < self.pages.count {
            let newController = MyPageViewController()
            newController.page = self.pages[newPageIndex]
            return newController
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `newController.page = viewController.page - 1` and 
 `newController.page = viewController.page + 1`
outputs an error... and In MyPageViewController how to add info for pages in viewdidload? if(page==1){...}else if(page==2){...}... ?

Comment: Can you link to a screenshot of the error? Or the error text?

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to cast the view controller. Code snippet updated.

Comment: In which class I have to add methods from viewDidLoad that I post, to start swipe pages in the view ?

Comment: Not sure, it depends. Try both.

Comment: As for setting pages, it's probably wise to use a model of some sort. Answer updated again.

Comment: I have UILabels - @IBOutlet connected to storyboard how to merge PageViewController with the labels ? And what data you want me to load in this line of code that you typed `// Load page data for self.page` I receive the data from CoreData in ViewController how to set the text for the labels there ?